# I am able to see the data fetched in console but i am not able to display?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am able to fetch data as it is only one record which i can see from my console but i am not abe to display due to something i have written wrong in code...But i am able to see the fetched data in the console the data is something like this
data: Array(4)
0: "Admin ID : 602"
1: "Name : Raj"
2: "Admin pin : 131195"
3: "PHONE NUMBER :9742894200"

```
import Axios from 'axios'
import  React, { Component }  from 'react'

class Admin extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state={
            posts: []
        }
    
    }
    componentDidMount(){
      const username  = this.props.location.username;
      Axios.get('http://localhost:9000/admin-service/admin/'+username)
      .then(response => {
          this.setState({ posts : response.data })
          console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

    render(){
      const { posts } = this.state
        return(
            <div>
                <h2>USER DASHBOARD:</h2>
                {
                  posts.length ?
                  posts.map(admin => <div key={admin.adminId}>{admin.adminId}</div>) :
                  null
                }
               
                 </div>
        )
    }

    
}

export default Admin
```

Comment: Can you share the response from the API?

Comment: Seems like your data endpoint returned you an array of strings as they are in the way that you've written them down.

Comment: [
    "Admin ID : 101",
    "Name : milansai",
    "Admin pin : 131198",
    "PHONE NUMBER :9742894200"
]

Comment: Above is the api response so how should i try to display it..

Comment: it seems the response is array of strings
you can't preview the adminId like this

the response should be like this
{
 adminId:101,
 name: "milansai"
}

Comment: data: adminId: 101 adminName: "milansai" adminPhone: "9742894200" adminPin: 131198     ----->THIS IS MY RESPONSE HOW SHOULD I DISPLAY IT??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce your issue and your code seems to work fine.

```
import React, { Component }  from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class Admin extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state={
            posts: []
        }
    
    }
    componentDidMount(){
      const username  = this.props.location.username;
      new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve({data: [{adminId: username + 0}, {adminId: username +1}]})
      })
      .then(response => {
          this.setState({ posts : response.data })
          console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

    render(){
      const { posts } = this.state
        return(
            <div>
                <h2>USER DASHBOARD:</h2>
                {
                  posts.length ?
                  posts.map(admin => <div key={admin.adminId}>{admin.adminId}</div>) :
                  null
                }
               
                 </div>
        )
    }

    
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Admin location={{username: 'test'}}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My guess it that the API response doesn't have the format you are expecting.
According to your console.log, you could change your template to  :

```
posts.length > 0 && posts[0].split(' : ').length > 1 ? 
    <div>{posts[0].split(' : ')[1]}</div> 
    : null
```

But ideally you should update your server response to return a proper object instead of an array of strings.

Comment: I have changed my API RESPONSE to                                                              adminId: 101
adminName: "milansai"
adminPhone: "9742894200"
adminPin: 131198     wHAT CHANGE I NEED TO MAKE NOW TO DISPLAY RECORDS?

Comment: Is your response an array or a single object? If it's an array, your initial solution should be working fine. If it's a single object, posts should be initialized to undefined and the template could be `posts? <div>posts.admin.adminId</div> : null`

Comment: data:
adminId: 101
adminName: "milansai"
adminPhone: "9742894200"
adminPin: 131198

Comment: This is my response how should i display it?

Comment: I will consider that your response is a JSON object and not a string. So at init

`this.state = {posts: undefined}`

Then in the template, you just need to read the appropriate fields (I think there was a typo in my previous answer, I meant posts.adminId and not posts.admin.adminId)

`<h2>USER DASHBOARD:</h2>{posts ? <div>{posts.adminId}</div>) : null}`

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(this.state.posts)
```

to see if your fetched data is being saved to state

Answer (score 0):

The response which you are receiving from the API is actually array of strings

```
data = ["Admin ID : 602", "Name : Raj" , "Admin pin : 131195", "PHONE NUMBER : 9742894200"]
```

and you are trying to uses it as the object. It also seems like that you are expecting your keys to be in the camel case so either you can fix this in your backend or you can write an adapter on the frontend

```
var keysAdapters =(arrayOfStrings)=>{
   const obj={}

   arrayOfStrings.map(item =>{
       const [key, value]=item.split(':')
       obj[_.camelCase(key.trim())]=value.trim()
   })

   return obj
}
```

Here I have used _.camelCase from lodash for more info you can visit https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#camelCase

> Though there are various caveats using this approach like here you
> wont be able to differentiate between different primitives as all the
> values will be string. Thus you will loose various checks which you
> will need in the future.
>
> As well as your value cannot be an object here so
>
> I will recommend you to change the your data structure of response and
> use objects.